# Chinese characters in CentOS are garbled

Tags: php, centos

I have a CentOS 5.6 on Linode VPS, and a nginx, mysql, php installed.

But when I transfer my old data from my old server, which I have no shell, to this new server, all the Chinese characters are garbled, hence pictures that have chinese names become 404.

I tried to change `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` to below:

```
LANG="zh_CN.GB2312"
SUPPORTED="zh_CN.GB2312:zh_CN.UTF-8:zh_CN:zh:en_US.UTF-8:en_US:en"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

And I also installed some fonts.

But that didn't help at all.

Now the mediawiki I run on the server cannot show pictures in Chinese name at all. So does wordpress.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that `wget` always encoding Chinese characters when transfer. Everything works fine when I use `lftp`.

Comment: How'd you do the transfer?  The encoding may have been messed up in the process.  Also - if you manually fix the name of the file, is it then served correctly?

Comment: How did you transfer the files. What filesystem are you storing them on on the new server?

Comment: @Shane I use wget in my current server, transfer using FTP. @Patrick Since I use a VPS as my server, the filesystem is not sure. I tried `fdisk` just now and it said it's unknown.@Shane After edit `i18n `file, some system hints become Chinese, such when I try to `rm` files. I also tried to rename some english files to chinese name, but it turned out to be 404. Also, even the system hints become Chinese, the file name I manually fixed shows Chinese, the old Chinese file still unreadable.

Comment: Ok - so if I understand correctly, there's two problems. 1. Files can be renamed on the filesystem to have Chinese characters with no problem, but are not served by the web server, giving a 404 instead, and 2. The existing files' names were messed up in the transfer.  Does that sound correct - are the names on the filesystem working as expected after you rename them, aside from issues with the web server?

Comment: @ShaneMadden You're right. I just found that when transfering, `wget` always tries to use base64 to encode Chinese characters. So that's why the file names garbled. Then I use another FTP tool called `lftp`. Now everything is fine. I still don't know why the name I manually fix is still garbled. Maybe it's because PUTTY's font encoding? Anyway, thanks^^

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed Chineses Langauage support?

```
yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"
```